# PHP don't return to old funciton after completing called function

Tags: php, mysql

My php script fetch data from a db (id, name, path, status, tags, date), then php scans the project directory for all html, php, css and js files and sort them into 4 arrays. After that it formatted the output.
At the sortFiles function it checks if there are a folder and it calls the same function if it detects a folder. It works fine but after the first folder php don't jump back into the first foreach loop and then its done... Here is my code:

```
    function sortFiles($dir,$name){
        foreach ($dir as $file) {
            $tmp = explode(".", $file);
            if($tmp[1] === "html" || $tmp[1] === "css" || $tmp[1] === "js" || $tmp[1] === "php"){
                $tmpArray = array();
                $url = "http://www.nimmi.de/" . $GLOBALS["entry"][1] . "/" . $name . $file;
                //$GLOBALS["output"] .=  "NAME: " . $name;
                array_push($tmpArray,$name . $file);
                array_push($tmpArray,$url);
                switch ($tmp[1]) {
                    case 'html':
                        array_push($GLOBALS["html"],$tmpArray);
                        break;
                    case 'php':
                        array_push($GLOBALS["php"],$tmpArray);
                        break;
                    case 'css':
                        array_push($GLOBALS["css"],$tmpArray);
                        break;
                    case 'js':
                        array_push($GLOBALS["js"],$tmpArray);
                        break;

                    default:
                        die("Unknown filetype");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if(strpos($file, '.') === false) {
                $GLOBALS["paths"] .= $file . "/";
                $GLOBALS["dirpath"] .= "/" . $file;
                $subdir = scandir($GLOBALS["dirpath"]);
                sortFiles($subdir,$GLOBALS["paths"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Does someone know the problem ?

Comment: @developerwjk sry i think my question wasn't exactly enought, i mean the foreach loop in the sortFiles function :)

Comment: I didn't even realize the code was that long. `sortFiles($dir,"");` was the last part I saw. Didn't see the scrollbar. Lol.

Comment: Where do you test if `$file` is a folder? You test for a bunch of suffixes, but if it doesn't have one of them you just assume it's a folder.

Comment: If only the `sortFiles()` function is relevant for this question you should edit your question and remove the unnecessary code.

Comment: I don't believe you when you say the loop is stopping. Try putting `echo "$file<br>";` at the top of the loop, and see what it shows.

Comment: @Cyclone sry, i fix it immediately

Comment: @Barmar .
..
css
.
..
main.css
index.html
js
i don't mean after calling the function again (if it founds a folder) it don't return to the foreach loop)

Comment: @Nimmi - Wouldn't it be better to check if it's a folder using `is_dir()` instead, I mean since it's perfectly valid for a file not to have an extension.

Comment: @Cyclone thx for the hint, i am new in php developing so i don't know much methods and stuff at the moment. I will try it out. :)

Comment: It nests down the directory paths by appending to a string. How does it unnest when it reaches the end of the current directory? Should you be using '$GLOBALS["dirpath"] ' as a 'stack' and pushing and popping the current directory to it? i.e. array_push($GLOBALS["dirpath"], $file) ;and array_pop(GLOBALS["dirpath"]) at the end.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you sorted it out :-) You are new to 'php' but not to 'programming'. Makes my life easier.

Comment: I suggest you post an answer so that others may find out how you fixed it. You can accept your own answers. It also will stop people who wish to help, checking it when the do not need to.

Comment: @RyanVincent ok, i do it later when i am back on my pc

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION(thanks to Ryan Vincent):

```
function sortFiles($dir,$name){//$dir --> directory to query, $name --> subfolder names
        foreach ($dir as $file) {//iterate through all files and sort them
            $tmp = explode(".", $file);//splitts the file string into the name and the extension
            if($tmp[1] === "html" || $tmp[1] === "css" || $tmp[1] === "js" || $tmp[1] === "php"){//checks the extension
                $tmpArray = array();//wrapper array
                $url = "../" . $GLOBALS["entry"][1] . "/" . $name . $file;//assemble the $url
                array_push($tmpArray,$name . $file);//push the $name into the wrapper array
                array_push($tmpArray,$url);//push the $url into the wrapper array
                //push the wrapper into the specific extension array
                switch ($tmp[1]) {
                    case 'html':
                        array_push($GLOBALS["html"],$tmpArray);
                        break;
                    case 'php':
                        array_push($GLOBALS["php"],$tmpArray);
                        break;
                    case 'css':
                        array_push($GLOBALS["css"],$tmpArray);
                        break;
                    case 'js':
                        array_push($GLOBALS["js"],$tmpArray);
                        break;

                    default:
                        die("Unknown filetype");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if(strpos($file, '.') === false) {//checks the $file if it is an folder
                array_push($GLOBALS["dirpath"], "/" . $file);//adds the subfolder to the directory
                $pathstr = implode("", $GLOBALS["dirpath"]);//unite the array to a string
                $subdir = scandir($pathstr);//scans the directory
                $dirname = explode($GLOBALS["dirpath"][0], $pathstr);//get the subfolder path as string
                sortFiles($subdir,$dirname[1] . "/");//call this function again to sort all files in the subfolder
                array_pop($GLOBALS["dirpath"]);//removes the last directory
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try without this line

```
die("Unknown filetype");
```

This might be breaking the nested loops.

Comment: If that's being executed, he wouldn't get any output at all other than the error.

Comment: It's impossible to get to that line. The `switch` is inside an `if` statement that only gets executed if the extension is one of those 4 types.